# Scroll event triggers multiple times even when debounced

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

I have the following component where on scroll to the end, we load more data to page.

I am loading 12 images at a time, when we reach the end of page.

But at present, it easily triggers approx 10 api calls each time instead of 1.

Ending up with a lot more images then intended at a time.

There are 2 issues here closely related to on scroll data load.

1. During initial load, api called with page 1 which is right. But When we scroll, the api call triggers
   and fetches same data again for page 1 during the first scroll. But page has been set to 2 after initial load. Why is it not loading page 2 instead? This only happens for first scroll. From then on is fine, data wise.
2. As mentioned, why is it triggering multiple api calls on scroll?
   I have debounce and using the isLoading state to control it which doesn't seem to matter.

The component

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
import useStore from "../utils/store.js"; // zustand sore
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {fetchItems} from "../utils/rest.js";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.jsx";

const Layout = () => {
 const setItems = useStore((state) => state.setItems);
 const page = useStore((state) => state.page);
 const setPage = useStore((state) => state.setPage);

 const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // hook or zustand state, same outcome

 const debouncedFetchItems = debounce(() => fetchItems(page), 50);

 const updatePageAndItems = (newItems) => {
  setPage();
  setItems(newItems);
 };

 const handleScroll = () => {
  const offset = 1000;
   if (!isLoading && window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight - offset) {
    setIsLoading(true);
     const promise = debouncedFetchItems();
     promise?.then(newItems => {
      updatePageAndItems(newItems)
      setIsLoading(false)
     });
   }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   fetchItems(page).then(newItems => updatePageAndItems(newItems));
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
 },[page]);

 return (
   <MyComponent /> {/* This component loads data based on using the global state value from items */}
 );
};

export default Layout;
```

Just for reference, this is store.js.

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { combine } from 'zustand/middleware'

const initialValues = {
  items: [],
  page: 1,
}

const useStore = create(
  combine(
    { ...initialValues },
    (set) => ({
      setItems: (newItems) => set((state) => ({ items: [...state.items, ...newItems] })),
      setPage: () => set((state) => ({ page: state.page + 1 })),
    })
  ),
)

export default useStore;
```

Note:

I can't do this. (no dependency)

```
 useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
 },[]);
```

It doesn't multi trigger api calls in this case. But it permanently ends up taking page as value 1. handleScroll never considers the state getting updated.

Thus this works, but as mentioned, ends up with multiple api calls.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
 },[page]);
```

UPDATE:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }
 }, [page]);
```

Comment: How about clearning up the listeners when the component re-renders? I see on every re-render the `handleScroll` function is getting redefined.

Comment: @mandy8055 Did add cleanups like shown under UPDATE: above. Same outcome.

Comment: the dependency should be `handleScroll` not `page`

Comment: can you check the `scrollY , innerHeight , scrollHeight  `in `handleScroll` function? what about trying to move the scroll event to `onScroll` in your `MyComponent`  and use `useRef` to handle the scroll event? I made a demo and hopefully it could help https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-77ca2s?file=src%2FApp.js